# Error while copying Data from one workbook to another workbook with missing last row

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code that is copying data from one workbook to another the code is

```
Sub DataMerger()
    Dim MyFileName As String, MyPath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    MyPath = "C:\FilesToMerge\"
    MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")

    Do Until MyFileName = ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

            If Len(ws.Name) > 1 Then
                Worksheets(1).Activate
                LastRow1 = ws.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                strAddress2 = "T2:T" & LastRow1
                wsName = ws.Name
                ws.Range(strAddress2).Value = wsName

                Dim DataBlock As Range, Dest As Range
                Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
                Dim SheetOne As Worksheet, SheetTwo As Worksheet
                Set SheetOne = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
                Set SheetTwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                ' Set Dest = SheetTwo.Cells(1, 1)
                Set Dest = SheetTwo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
                MsgBox Dest, vbOKOnly, "Dest"

                With SheetOne
                    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    MsgBox LastRow, vbOKOnly, "LastRow"
                    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
                    MsgBox LastCol, vbOKOnly, "LastColumn"
                    Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                End With

                With DataBlock
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*ON*"
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dest
                End With

                With SheetOne
                    .AutoFilterMode = False
                    If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
                End With

            End If

            ActiveWorkbook.Close True

        Next

        wbName = ActiveSheet.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        MyFileName = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```

this code is going to folder "FilestoMerge" and opens the workbook and make worksheet(1) as active worksheet then copys the name of worksheet to column T.

After that it filters the data on column A with Value ON and copys data to another workbook. 
The data are copied perfectly but I have noticed that it misses the last row of the data, for example if last row where Data exist is 65434 it will only copy  data up to row 65433.

I have tried all the ways to figure out what is going wrong in this but have no luck. I believe the statement

```
Set Dest = SheetTwo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

is the main cause of the error but not sure.

I believe that data are copied perfectly from `SheetOne` to `sheetTwo` but on a lastrow it is overwriting when new data comes from another workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set Dest = SheetTwo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

Is setting dest as the last cell in column A with data in it.  The line is the same as going to the last cell on the sheet then hitting ctrl + up arrow.  You need to step down one row after doing that.

Try:

```
Set Dest = SheetTwo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1)
```

This will go to the last cell in column A with data then move down one.